# Why number of requests are reduced when number of Threads are increased?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a test suite which has many HTTP requests. Each HTTP requests have different number of threads but with 30 seconds as Ramp up time.

Set 1:
[image]

Set 2:
[image]

The difference between Set 1 and Set 2 are only in the number of Threads. Its exactly the double number of requests in Set 2. But you can see the total count is reduced. Why is this? i was expecting the number of requests also to go up when the number of Threads are increased.

Can someone please put some light into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tables don't tell the full story and the could be multiple explanations, for example:

- You increase number of threads by factor of 2
- Your application becomes overloaded hence response time increases
- So assuming the same test duration JMeter is able to execute less requests as it waits for response from previous request prior to sending a new one

So pay attention not only to number of requests but also check response time for all the samplers and correlation between increased amount of active users and response time by looking into i.e. [Response Times vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/) and [Transaction Throughput vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionThroughputVsThreads/) charts.

Aforementioned graphs can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager KPI vs KPI]